# recursively copy files with stripping prefix

Tags: linux, shell, recursion, cp

I'm trying to create a GNU Makefile rule that copies files (found via VPATH) from one directory to another, preserving their directory structure.

There are zillions of ways to do this (starting with `cp -r`) but it seems that none of them work in the context of `make`, where the copying is initiated in the *target* directory.

E.g.

```
  cp ../src/foo.c ../src/bar.c .
```

All the source files share a common directory (only *known* at runtime), and this common directory should be stripped away.

E.g.

```
  $ srcdir=../../knurgl
  $ cp ${srcdir}/src/foo.c ${srcdir}/src/bar.c .
  $ find . -type f
  ./src/foo.c
  ./src/bar.c
```

even though the common directory is known at runtime, it can be arbitrary and even include the current directory `.` (in which case the operation should be a nop).

## This is what i tried:

### cp

```
cp --parent ${srcdir}/src/foo.c ${srcdir}/src/bar.c .
```

but rightfully this refuses to work when called from the target directory (as it would always copy the files onto themselves).

### tar

```
tar c ${srcdir}/src/foo.c ${srcdir}/src/bar.c | tar x
```

this strips away any relative directories, but keeps the rest (so I end up with `./knurgl/src/foo.c` instead of `./src/foo.c`.

The `--strip-components` option doesn't help me much, as i don't know the depth of `${srcdir}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
cp --parent ${srcdir}/src/foo.c ${srcdir}/src/bar.c .
```

(which doesn't work because it doesn't strip `$srcdir`) you can write

```
(wd=$PWD; cd $srcdir; cp --parent src/foo.c src/bar.c $wd)
```

Answer (score 0):

`make` has built-in functions for handling strings. To replace `old_base_dir` with `new_base_dir` in the variable `path`, call:

```
$(path:old_base_dir/%=new_base_dir/%)
```

You can also let it perform the substitution on a list:

```
$(foreach path,$(path_list),$(path:old_base_dir/%=new_base_dir/%)
```

Here, the variable `path_list` contains multiple files. Note though that this will break if the file names contain spaces.

The [manual of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html) describes many more useful functions.